# java create instance from interface class

Tags: java, interface

Consider this is interface:

```
public interface Node {
    Node next();
    Node prev();
    void setNext(Node next);
    void setPrev(Node prev);
    void setVal(int val);
    int getVal();
}
```

I want know how I can instantiate this class, for example:

```
Node p = tail;
```

I would like to use it something like this.

Comment: Create a class that implements the interface, and then instantiate the new class: `Node p = new SomeClassThatImplementsNode();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant create instance for an interface , Instead make some class to implement this interface and create instance for that class

```
public class NodeImpl implements Node{
// your impl     
 }
```

then

```
 NodeImpl tail = new NodeImpl();
 Node p =tail;
```

Comment: You can just do: `Node tail = new NodeImpl();`

Answer (score 2):

`Node` is an *interface*, not an *interface class* (there is no such thing). In a nutshell, you cannot instantiate an interface or an abstract class; you can only instantiate a concrete class.

To take your example, if `tail` is of type that's either `Node` or is a class/interface that implements/extends `Node`, then the assignment will just work.

If you need to create a new object, the code would look something like:

```
public interface Node { ... }

public class NodeImpl implements Node { ... }

Node p = new NodeImpl();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the interface you can only do something like that for the initialization (anonymous class):

```
Node p = new Node() {
    public Node next() {}
    public Node prev() {}
    public void setNext(Node next) {}
    public void setPrev(Node prev) {}
    public void setVal(int val) {}
    public int getVal() {}
};
```

and implement all the methods. Otherwise you can create an example class:

```
class NodeImpl implements Node {
    public Node next() {}
    public Node prev() {}
    public void setNext(Node next) {}
    public void setPrev(Node prev) {}
    public void setVal(int val) {}
    public int getVal() {}
}
Node p = new NodeImpl();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a class implementing this interface.

But, you still could write:

```
Node n = new Node() {
  //and here you MUST implement all Node methods
};
```